# Getting "Tracking Not Installed" from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have double and triple checked and my code snippet is in the home page (http://www.eventridersassociation.org.uk/index.html).  But GA refuses to recognize it.

The page simply does a timed redirect to a Wordpress site (I have tried without timeout):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirect</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-6484009-3']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="http://eventridersassociation.org.uk/members/index.php">Loading.</a>
<script type="text/javascript">


  setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "http://eventridersassociation.org.uk/members/index.php"    

  }, 1000);



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Redirecting your page after 1 second? Try removing your redirect and see if that fixes it. if you are trying to track the number of people that get passed on to the other URL, try adding some campaign variables to track in the analytics on the page being directed to.

Comment: Why do you even do that -redirect why not set index.php as default page or do a htaccess 301 redirect ?

Comment: I tried without the redirect - problem was the same. The reason it is coded that way is a pragmatic fix as the original web developer had two Wordpress sites and I didn't want the one in the root.  I originally did a straight redirect, but research showed that this was one of the issues that might cause GA to report "Tracking Not Installed" and the timed redirect gives the GA code snippet a chance to run.

Comment: Well GA just started to work all of a sudden and now reports "Status: Receiving Data".  No changes to my code! It looks like GA can just take time to start working and I wasn't patient enough.

Comment: Thanks to those who tried to help

Answer (score 1):

I know you got it working on the first URL, but on the site you redirect to, you are calling the analytics script twice. Once correctly, and once without an ID. Are you using a plugin called "Cookie Control" or something like that? It's injected a second GA script in the footer of your site, but didn't set any of the variables. I would disable that plugin if I were you.

Here is the debug info for your tracking script on the original /index.html page:

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-6484009-3]": 
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]": 
Track Pageview
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.4.2d&utms=8&utmn=350399410&utmhn=eventridersassociation.org.uk&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1440x900&utmvp=1440x287&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=11.7%20r700&utmdt=Event%20Riders%20Association%20%7C%20We%20Are%20One%20sport%20%E2%80%A6%20One%20Voice&utmhid=1248347118&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eventridersassociation.org.uk%2Findex.html&utmp=%2Fmembers%2F&utmht=137…15147996%2Fgetting-tracking-not-installed-from-google-analytics%3B&utmu=q~
Account ID               : UA-6484009-3
Page Title               : Event Riders Association | We Are One sport … One Voice
Host Name                : eventridersassociation.org.uk
Page                     : /members/
Referring URL            : http://www.eventridersassociation.org.uk/index.html
Hit ID                   : 1248347118
Visitor ID               : 922109071
Session Count            : 1
Session Time - First     : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Session Time - Last      : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Session Time - Current   : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Campaign Time            : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : stackoverflow
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.7 r700
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1440x900
Browser Size             : 1440x287
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.4.2d
Cachebuster              : 350399410
```

And here is the debug info on the page you redirected to:

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-6484009-3]": 
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]": 
Track Pageview
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.4.2d&utms=9&utmn=1819301630&utmhn=eventridersassociation.org.uk&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1440x900&utmvp=1425x279&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=11.7%20r700&utmdt=Event%20Riders%20Association%20%7C%20We%20Are%20One%20sport%20%E2%80%A6%20One%20Voice&utmhid=238588836&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fmembers%2F&utmht=1371108346526&utmac=UA-6484009-3&utmcc=__utma%3D89671247.922109071.1371107723.1371107723.1371107723.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D89671247.1371107723.1.1.utmcsr%3Dstackoverflow.com%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fquestions%2F15147996%2Fgetting-tracking-not-installed-from-google-analytics%3B&utmu=q~
Account ID               : UA-6484009-3
Page Title               : Event Riders Association | We Are One sport … One Voice
Host Name                : eventridersassociation.org.uk
Page                     : /members/
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 238588836
Visitor ID               : 922109071
Session Count            : 1
Session Time - First     : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Session Time - Last      : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Session Time - Current   : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Campaign Time            : Thu Jun 13 2013 02:15:23 GMT-0500 (CDT)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : stackoverflow
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.7 r700
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1440x900
Browser Size             : 1425x279
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.4.2d
Cachebuster              : 1819301630
```